# SFTP listing directory

Tags: php, python, sftp

I'm trying to make a connection to a secure sftp site, however I'm not able to list the directory,however, it's possible to connect using python "expect" or php"ssh2_connect" but it gives me the following mesg: Received disconnect from xx.xx.xx.

If I use a GUI appliction like winscp I'm able to go to the sftp server and retrieve files.

I need to script it thus a cli interface is needed.

PS: just in case someone ran into this. I'm trying to connect to Avisena.com  sftp server

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do this easily with [paramiko](http://www.lag.net/paramiko), checkout [SFTP with Python](http://commandline.org.uk/python/sftp-python/)

Comment: Enable logging to file with paramiko.util.log_to_file('/tmp/paramiko.log') and check the log for problems.